# Any ideas how to make calls from Alexa to Alexa?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I wanna make a lambda function that allow me to make a call from own Alexa device to another one. As I know, it can be possible with the last update by using this API: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-smart-properties/asp-in-senior-living-communications-api.html Is anyone know something about it? Mb you can give me a link, where I can read something about it. Or mb it's just impossible and you can give me some advices how to make it by other ways. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but at this point there is nothing in Alexa Smart Properties Communication API that will allow you to initiate a call between 2 devices.